# How to type text with hat "^" in html?

Tags: html

I want to display text with "^" symbol over that.
I have tried to do as follow:

```
<span style="position: relative; left: 11px; bottom: 12px; transfrom: scale(4,0.5)">^</span> ABC.
```

But the "transform" property doesn't work.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: can you try `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `display:inline-block`
this should work

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more example (or `A&#x0302;BC`):

```html
A&#770;BC
```

Answer (score 1):

You just type the version of the character with the [circumflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex). It has no special meaning in HTML, so you can use it raw. You just need to ensure you are using a character encoding which supports it (and you need an exceptionally good reason not to use UTF-8 any time this century).

```
ÂBC
```

How you type it depends on your platform. On a Mac you can simply hold down the A key until a menu of diacritics pops up. On Windows you can use the Character Map utility (unless you routinely use a language which includes those characters in which case you probably have a keyboard configured for it already.

Answer (score -3):

This works for me and no need for transform property.

```
<span style="position: relative; left: 13px; bottom: 8px;">^</span> ABC.
```

Comment: This is why I need to scale the "^" so that it fit the length of the text.